# Dynamic nav menu timeout function not clearing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am trying to make a navigation menu where, on certain items, there is a dropdown menu. When you hover this item, it changes the content of a central dropdown menu called NavListDropdown. I want to do it this way so that I can implement animations and other cool stuff.

Here is my Nav code:

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  const [isItemHovered, setIsItemHovered] = useState(false);
  const [isDropdownVisible, setIsDropdownVisible] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownContent, setDropdownContent] = useState(null);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);

  const mouseEnterHandler = (content, activeItem) => {
    // setIsDropdownVisible(true);
    setIsItemHovered(true);
    setDropdownContent(content);
    setActiveItem(activeItem);
  };

  const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
    // setIsDropdownVisible(false);
    setIsItemHovered(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    if (isItemHovered) {
      setIsDropdownVisible(true);
    } else {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsDropdownVisible(false);
      }, 1500);
    }

    return () => {
      if (isItemHovered && timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [isItemHovered]);

  const listItems = listItemsData.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <NavListItem
        key={i}
        index={i}
        item={item}
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler}
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveHandler}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <nav className={classes.Nav}>
      <ul className={classes.NavList}>{listItems}</ul>
      <NavListDropdown
        isVisible={isDropdownVisible}
        content={dropdownContent}
        activeItem={activeItem}
      />
      <div className={classes.NavLogo}>Logo</div>
      <div className={classes.NavCart}>
        <NavCart />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

What is supposed to happen is, once the user unhovers the item, a timeout is set to hide the dropdown. However, if the user howevers the same/another element, this timeout should cancel. It works at first, but when you quickly hover back and forth between items, it is as if the previous timeout has not been cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I shouldn't include the conditional statement in the useEffect. So it would look like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    if (isItemHovered) {
      setShowDropdown(true);
    } else {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowDropdown(false);
      }, 400);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [isItemHovered]);
```